# Why socket has lower latency with high qps

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

I set up a ping-pong test on a Linux computer. The server is responsible for accepting socket link and responsing some message, and client connect to server then loop for requesting server and waiting for response, QPS can be configured by sleep time.
client.cc

```cpp
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int64_t cpuwide_time_ns() {
  struct timespec now;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
  return now.tv_sec * 1000000000L + now.tv_nsec;
}

int64_t cpuwide_time_us() { return cpuwide_time_ns() / 1000; }

// Big Endian (network order)
unsigned int fromBytes(unsigned char b[4]) {
  return b[3] | b[2] << 8 | b[1] << 16 | b[0] << 24;
}

void toBytes(unsigned int x, unsigned char (&b)[4]) {
  b[3] = x;
  b[2] = x >> 8;
  b[1] = x >> 16;
  b[0] = x >> 24;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int sock, valread;
  struct sockaddr_in address;
  int opt = 1;
  int addrlen = sizeof(address);

  // We'll be passing uint32's back and forth
  unsigned char recv_buffer[4] = {0};
  unsigned char send_buffer[4] = {0};

  // Create socket for TCP server
  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  // Set TCP_NODELAY so that writes won't be batched
  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_NODELAY, &opt, sizeof(opt));
  address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  address.sin_port = htons(8080);

  // Accept one client connection
  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t)addrlen) != 0) {
    throw("connect failed");
  }

  unsigned int lastReceived = 0;
  uint64_t elp = 0;
  size_t requestCount = 1000;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < requestCount; i++) {
    auto start = cpuwide_time_us();
    toBytes(++lastReceived, send_buffer);
    write(sock, send_buffer, 4);
    valread = read(sock, recv_buffer, 4);
    lastReceived = fromBytes(recv_buffer);
    elp += cpuwide_time_us() - start;
    usleep(1000);
  }
  printf("average cost %d us", elp / requestCount);
}
```

server.cc

```cpp
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Big Endian (network order)
unsigned int fromBytes(unsigned char b[4]) {
  return b[3] | b[2] << 8 | b[1] << 16 | b[0] << 24;
}

void toBytes(unsigned int x, unsigned char (&b)[4]) {
  b[3] = x;
  b[2] = x >> 8;
  b[1] = x >> 16;
  b[0] = x >> 24;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
  struct sockaddr_in address;
  int opt = 1;
  int addrlen = sizeof(address);
  unsigned char recv_buffer[4] = {0};
  unsigned char send_buffer[4] = {0};

  // Create socket for TCP server
  server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  address.sin_port = htons(8080);
  // sopt(server_fd, TCP_CORK, 1);
  bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));

  listen(server_fd, 3);

  // Accept one client connection
  new_socket =
      accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t *)&addrlen);
  printf("Connected with client!\n");

  setsockopt(new_socket, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_NODELAY, &opt, sizeof(opt));

  // sopt(new_socket, TCP_CORK, 1);
  int counter = 0;
  unsigned int x = 0;

  while (true) {
    valread = read(new_socket, recv_buffer, 4);
    x = fromBytes(recv_buffer);
    toBytes(x + 1, send_buffer);
    write(new_socket, send_buffer, 4);
    ++counter;
  }
}
```

QPS = 100k, usleep(10), the average latency is 37us,
QPS = 1k, usleep(1000), the average latency is 147us.

Is there any idea to explain why  does this happen？

Comment: Borked anyway due to failure to comprehend TCP streaming and lack of correct/complete handling of system calls.

Comment: You don't need to include your own functions to convert endianness, the standard library includes those. If you, instead of writing `unsigned int fromBytes(unsigned char b[4])`, write `unsigned int fromBytes(unsigned char b[static 4])`, this will enable optimizations and allow the compiler to perform bounds-checking (that you pass an array that is large enough).

Comment: @JohnScott After removing these unnecessary functions, and I test again, the result remains the same as above.

Comment: Please do not edit the essential parts of the code once you have posted it with questions about it, especially once people have begun to analyze, suggest and otherwise comment.   The original content is what is what they are addressing.  If you change it during that process it becomes a confusing mess.  I have rolled your edit back to original.  It is fine to remove  or change content in your development system, but leave the content of your question unchanged (except maybe for formatting improvements, which your post does not need.)

Comment: Maybe the server gets de-scheduled (or is colder if it was previously descheduled) when it's been sleeping in `read` for a millisecond? Have you tried pinning it to a core with FIFO scheduling and high priority? (NB. If you do this, don't pin it to core zero)

Comment: Why would it sleep in read()?  The read will block until 1,2,3 or 4 bytes can be loaded into the buffer.  I suspect that, apart from the lack of correct TCP and system call return handling, the nagle algorithm is causing issues. Pinning and faffing about with priorities is extremely unlikely to help.

Comment: @Useless Yes, I did, server is bound to core 1 with nice -20, same as client.

Comment: @MartinJames  I have set tcp_noreplay on socket to disable nagle algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that. If you have non-blocking sockets and you're not explicitly handling `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN` error codes, then this is completely broken.

Comment: @Ds.Hale my apologies - so you have:)

Comment: This seems to be C++. Please remove the C tag. Also, consider using `std::cout` instead of `printf`, but if you do use `printf`, at least use correct format specifier (or type cast for the argument). Also, your `throw` seems to leak `sock`. Also, check error code of _all_ socket related calls, and use `errno` to know which error.